# How can we change the language of our web application in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#-3.0

I made a web application in ASP.NET on CMS in which every page contains data from a database.  When we are using globalization on my application the static content elements are changed according to selecting the language, but data that comes from database is not changed.  How can we implement globalization for dynamic content?

Comment: which CMS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have localized content in your database i.e. have different text for different cultures. If yes, then you need to pass current/selected culture to database while fetching (/updating) the data. There can be various schemes for storing localized data in database - look at [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377530/data-localization-in-sql-server-with-guids-or/#2377721) for one of the simple but workable scheme.